# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word: where is the default version defined when multiple versions of Word are installed?

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I have multiple versions of Word installed on my machine (Word03 and Word07). Currently Word07 is set as default version (which I also checked in the Windows registry).
In a C# project I'm using the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` library by referencing Microsoft Word 12.0 Object Library.
But when I create a new application by calling

```
Application app = new Application();
```

version 11.0 (Word03) is used anyway. So I'm wondering where the default version is defined, that is used when creating new applications.

Comment: How do you know version 11 is used?

Comment: by checking app.Version. I also checked app.Path, which points to the working directory of Word03.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a referrence you will find it there
i.e. it must be like 8.0 or close to this number (for 2003 version)
so first remove the reference for 12.0 version, and then add the one
with lesser version mentioned

Comment: What I want to achieve is that Word07 is used instead of Word03. So I think version 12.0 should be the right one.

Comment: Yes it is, I too was working recently where word and excel references must be added.

Comment: Well, I'm using version 12 as mentioned above, which should be the right version for Word07. But still Word03 is used, which should not happen and which I want to avoid. So what exactly should I refer to?

Comment: I also have installed VS 2010 and I just checked in the Add Reference dialogue, there is Version 14 as well, so try finding that
You can also download the Interop Assemblies from microsoft web sites for 2007 version, and there was some tool that makes you able to extract any particular assembley from a dll package/file